# Ubuntu 16.04.3 and 17.04 problems

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, shutdown, startup, 17.04

just got my XPS 9560 with Nvidia gtx 1050 graphics card, trying to install ubuntu on it, dual boot with windows 10 (AHCI). However, I encountered a few issues...

16.04.3:
Cannot shut down or restart -- doesn't matter I do it with GUI, or do it under sudo command in Terminal, when I try to shut down or restart, it simply freezes, meaning that, the crusor disappears and everything else absolutely freezes there. Same thing will happen if I try Ubuntu booting into my external USB. (It also happens right after the installation when the system ask me to resart)

17.04:
Cannot login. Everytime I turn on Ubuntu, the "Ubuntu" with dots under it will appears, then it hangs there. However, if I use recovery mode and resume, I am able to login and everything looks normal. This does not happen when I try Ubuntu on external USB. Some people suggest it might be the graphics card issue. However, even after installing the Nvidia driver, the issue does not go away. Plus 16.04.3 does not have this issue (it cannot shut down though). Everything else works, 17.04 can shut down normally.

I have used Ubuntu for more than a year and totally love it. However, I would love it more if Canonial can deal with those issues...

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause to your problems is the combination of the nvidia graphics card and the Intel on-board one. When you are on first boot - installation process - also try the following:

```
### Add nvidia drivers
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
# More Info on https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
sudo apt update
# nvidia-375 is the lts branch usable with CUDA/CUDNN. Change if you want
sudo apt-get install nvidia-375
# Nvidia Xserver Settings from dash
# Swap GPU's from Prime Profiles
```

Note: My system doesn't shut down (i5-7300hq + 1050Ti) when I select the on board cpu on the prime profiles instead of the on board card. So after the installation of the relevant drivers make sure you select the dedicated gpu option at the prime profiles.

Further note: This is kinda expected. System76 - a dedicated Linux vendor - fuses the Intel iGPU so it's like it is not there at all. They do it Optimus because support in Linux needs more work :(

Comment: Cool. So automatic switch gpu is not possible for Ubuntu? That's kinda sad. Thanks for the info. Have you tried to install driver downloaded from nvidia website though?